# What is the hyphen after the ENV variable DOCKER_REGISTRY for in a docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, amazon-ecr

In my docker-compose files, my image tag is like so

`image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi`

However the ENV variable is just DOCKER_REGISTRY, so what's the hyphen for?

Also, now I'm wanting to push these images to ECR, when I set the DOCKER_REGISTRY to my ECR instance, there is no `/`, between the `DOCKER_REGISTRY` and `webapi` part, so I guess I need to change it to look like `image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}/webapi`? But maybe only for my non-dev docker-compose files?

Comment: The second part of my question was solved as easy as adding a `/` to the end of my `DOCKER_REGISTRY` env variable... the simple answer is always the best :D :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` is part of the syntax for variable substitution, which is based on the standard described here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

```
${SOME_VAR-<default value if variable is not set>}
```

In this case, no default value is set, so it's redundant.

Comment: Cheers, that makes a lot of sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a /. it's not a path, it's the name of the image.

Comment: You can build and push images if you have the `build` and `image` keys set, which is what I'm trying to do. As per the docs, this is valid: `registry/repository`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/